# ¿Por qué recibo el error XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd al hacer un GET en angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sap, get

Primero de todo decir que este es mi primer proyecto con AngularJs y que trabajo con Visual Studio 2013. Mi intención es obtener datos de SAP para mostrarlos en mi aplicación web y obtengo:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.
File: index.html
```

Mi controllador

```
app.controller('searchStockController', function ($scope, $translate, 
$location, $window, $log, $http) {

$log.info("[searchStockController] Initializing");

//Define user password
var userandpass = "user:password";

//Encode String
var encodedString = btoa(userandpass);

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "http://172.20.0.53:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZESGW_LOGIN_USER_SRV/DelegadoUserSet(Usuario='delegado',Password='password_delegado')",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedString,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})
.success(function(data, status){
console.log("Success.");
})
.error(function (err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err);
})
```

Tengo mi pc conectado a la VPN. Si **realizo la petición via URL funciona**, me devuelve el valor esperado (en este caso un XML o un JSON si pido ese formato). En mi projecto existen varias vistas con sus controladores, cada uno en un fichero js separado del resto y el ng-app="MiApp" está definido al principio en mi fichero index.

index.html

```
<body>
<div ng-app="app">
    <!-- Aquí se inyectan las diferentes vistas de la app -->
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

En mi fichero manifest tengo declaradas las capabilities que tengo entendido que son necesarias para tener Internet:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: Que navegador estas utilizando?

Comment: He probado la url tanto en IE11 como Google Chrome (conectado en la VPN) y funciona en los dos casos. Cuando no me funciona es cuando ejecuto mi proyecto en "Local Machine".

Comment: "Local Machine"? Puedes explicarte?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2013 creando una aplicación Windows el "Local Machine" es el modo en que ejecuto mi solución de Visual con esto quiero decir que NO uso simulador o una tablet o móvil Windows.